# The commit of parent of parent branch is not showing up in the github.com

Tags: git, github, git-merge

There was a branch A which was branched out from develop and then there was a further subranch of A which was named B (suppose). Now the state is like this develop --> A --> B.

So once I merge A into develop, what happens to branch B.

Now I want to merge the latest develop changes into my current branch B, but the merge push is not showing up in the github.com but when I do git log it is in the logging tree.

I want to merge develop branch into my own branch B but the commit is not showing up in the remote, but there is a merge commit in the logging tree.

Comment: Did you push all your local commits? And the question is currently unanswerable. You have to at least include the top of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate develop branchA branchB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have new commits on develop which are not in branch B:

```
d--d--d--d--D--D (develop)
     /
    /
a--a (A)
    \
     b--b--b (B)
```

If you want to test B based on those new (D) commits, I would recommend to *rebase* `B` (assuming you are the only one working on it):

```
 git rebase --onto develop $(git merge-base B A) B

 # if there are no new commits on A, you can use instead:
 git rebase --onto develop A B
```

That will replay all commits from `B`, starting from one *after* `A`, or after the common commit between `B` and `A` (`git merge-base B A`) up to `B HEAD`.

```
                 b'--b'--b' (B)
                /
d--d--d--d--D--D (develop)
     /
    /
a--a (A)
```

That way, no need to merge an integration branch like `develop` to anything: its history remain untouched.
You rewrite `B` on top of `develop`, and can test it with everything develop has already integrated.